# How can I write a code and call it a name and use the name many times within the same xaml.cs file?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Please I am new to Xamarin forms and C# programming

How can I write a code and call it a name and use the name many times within the same xaml.cs file?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Write a method with your logic and call them wherever you need. You can refer the [official C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods) for more details.

```
[scope] [return type] MethodName (parameter1, parameter2, .....)
{
    //Your logic
}
//Note that parameters are not mandatory. Your method can be parameterless as well. 

//For example
private void SimpleMethod()
{
     //Your logic
}
```

I hope that helps.